# php: parse error on mysql query

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a4999406/public_html/willingLog.html on line 48

on the following code (line 48 is first row of this code):

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($j=0; $j<$rows: ++$j)
{
    echo 'ID: '     . mysql_result($result, $j, 'id') . '<br />';
    echo 'First: '  . mysql_result($result, $j, 'first') . '<br />';
    echo 'Last: '   . mysql_result($result, $j, 'last') . '<br />';
    echo 'Email: '  . mysql_result($result, $j, 'email') . '<br />';
}
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes it gets the line number wrong. What does line 47 look like? Or maybe a few lines further up than that?

Comment: You have a `:` where you intend a `;` here `for ($j=0; $j<$rows: ++$j)` after `$rows`

Comment: that was dumb of me.  i'm still getting the same error, however.

Comment: PHP's complaining about the $row on your line 48, meaning you've got a missing semicolon or other minor syntax error on the lines above it. And other than you're using mysql functions, this quest has nothing to do with mysql, it's just an innocent bystander caught in the PHP crossfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a missing semicolon, closing brace, or closing bracket on the line or lines above. Only logical explanation for that error.

Comment: i'm an idiot.   it's a good catch, but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code, or at least +- 5 lines above/below? The : in the for loop wouldn't have caused that error.

Comment: ok.. i'm truly an amateur and an idiot.  it was a missing semicolon.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. Glad we figured it out. On a side note, you should use PDO or MySQLi for new applications. mysql_ functions are deprecated. (also, feel free to click the accept button on my answer ;) )

Comment: does that mean mysql is being phased out?  my book is on mysql.  is MySQLi very different?

Comment: No, MySQL is the same RDBMS. The PHP extension that you are using, php_mysql, is ancient. See: [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) of PHP for more details.

Comment: thanks for the info.  i'm making my way through the book: "Learning PHP, MySql, and JavaScript (Animal Guide)".  Can you recommend a better book to learn from?

Comment: Not from experience, unfortunately. The best PHP book I've ever read was _PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice_ which didn't cover MySQL. From a quick Amazon search, _Beginning PHP and MySQL: From Novice to Professional_ looks somewhat promising.

Comment: @dwstein, this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Comment: @dwstein, on second note, none of the 4 PHP books there use mysqli or PDO, so forget my last comment.

Comment: If you want a well documented abstraction layer or ORM, you could try Doctrine, however; it's best to start with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The issue this: `for ($j=0; $j<$rows: ++$j)` change the colon to a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

there were two errors: 1) used a colon instead of a semicolon in line 48, and 2) i was missing a semicolon above.

complete amateur maneuver.  sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little strange - so many seperate mysql querys in that loop, you could just use fetch_assoc instead. Also looks like you're going to stop one row too early from that for loop. Use this instead;

```
$sql = "SELECT id, first, last, email FROM table";
while ($mysql_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "  ID: {$mysql_array['id']} <br />
            First: {$mysql_array['first']} <br />
            Last: {$mysql_array['last']} <br />
            Email: {$mysql_array['email']} <br />";
}
```

Also, consider switching to Mysqli_ - Mysql_ is deprecated.